# Selenium Python, send number input value to li in HTML

Tags: python, selenium

I am automating a script that selects a product quantity, but this particular site uses +/- click buttons and has no dropdown or input field for the quantities that are read from CSV.

Rather than emulating button presses of the +/- for the quantities, you can manually edit the HTML below with the desired number and click the add to cart for the same effect.

Is it possible to edit the HTML when there is no form to do so on the site?
Or do I have to emulate clicks for the desired quantity.
I am using Pandas to read the CSV and is working code from another project.

Thank you if you can help

```
https://www.matsukiyo.co.jp/store/online/p/4902888248269

<ul class="count">
        <li>数量</li>
        <li class="minus disable"><a href="#">－</a></li>
        <li class="num" id="addToCartQty" data-code="99">1</li>
        <li class="plus"><a href="#">＋</a></li>
        </ul>
```

You can change the `data-code="99">1</li>` from 1 to 99 and it will update but is this possible in Selenium as I cannot find the right selector to do so. I have a feeling this is not possible?

The current code I am trying is sending clicks but I am not able to send the number of clicks I want and am stuck for a solution either way.

How can I send the value from the CSV to dictate the number of clicks?
Or how can I write the value to the li HTML?

```
driver.get(web_url+str(UPC[i]))
try:
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "＋").click
    # I want to add the number of clicks here(str(quantity[i]))
    link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p.button.cart")
    link.click()
except:
    print("Product Number: "+str(UPC[i])+" Sold Out!")
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the element containing the count is located by id='addToCartQty' so what you can do is simply

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#addToCartQty').sendKeys("your value");
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#addToCartQty').sendKeys("value", "your value");
```

or

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#addToCartQty')
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='enter the value here';", element);
```

Don't forger to change "your value" or 'enter the value here' with a number you wish to input there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately as the addToCartQty is not a selectable item on the webpage the sendkeys does not update the value in the li and the operation does not perform the numerical input using the suggested CSS selectors

I tried the Javascript, it looks like it should work but I a m not familiar with JS, I only added the value and ran the code without success, I will test further, but initially it did not work, perhaps for the same above reasons

Thank you for your assitance

Comment: OK, did you try doing with the JavaScript? The third option.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to edit the html and execute the script using execute_script() method

```
script="document.getElementsByClassName('num')[0].value="+your_value+" ;"
driver.execute_script(script)
```

You can check this by running the script in your browser console,it will induce your required value to the html tag.

Comment: `script="driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#addToCartQty')[0].value="+ 3 +" ;"
        driver.execute_script(script)


element = driver.find_element_by_ID('#addToCartQty')
        JavascriptExecutor
        jse = (JavascriptExecutor)
        driver;
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='3';", element);`

@Prophet  @Aswin K
Thank you for the suggestions, however after spending several hours of testing, the result is always the same and I am unable to change the value using the JS,  I have tried several different combinations of selectors, Class, ID, xpath, all to no avail

Comment: I tried the aforementioned browser console and the following result is 3, but the actual value is not written to the 'num' class
`document.getElementsByClassName('num')[0].value="3'`

Is there anything I can provide to help understand and resolve the issue better?
Thank you if you have any further suggestions